# Bash script to change file names of different extension

Tags: linux, bash

we are working on a angularjs project, where the compiled output contains lot of file extensions like js,css, woff, etc.. along with individual dynamic hashing as part of file name.

I am working on simple bash script to search the files belonging to the mentioned file extensions and moving to some folder with hashing removed by 
searching for first instance of '.'.

**Please note file extension .woff and .css should be retained.**

```
/src/main.1cc794c25c00388d81bb.js   ==> /dst/main.js  
/src/polyfills.eda7b2736c9951cdce19.js ==> /dst/polyfills.js  
/src/runtime.a2aefc53e5f0bce023ee.js ==> /dst/runtime.js  
/src/styles.8f19c7d2fbe05fc53dc4.css ==> /dst/styles.css  
/src/1.620807da7415abaeeb47.js  ==> /dst/1.js  
/src/2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3.js  ==> /dst/2.js  
/src/some-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff  ==> /dst/some-webfont.woff  
/src/Web_Bd.d2138591460eab575216.woff ==> /dst/Web_Bd.woff
```

**Bash code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Process web binary files!

echo Processing the name change for js files!!!!!!!!!!!!!
sfidx=0;
SFILES=./src/*.js #{js,css,voff}
DST=./dst/

for files in $SFILES
do
        echo $(basename $files)
        cp $files ${DST}"${files//.*}".js  
        sfidx=$((sfidx+1))
done
echo Number of target files detected in srcdir $sfidx!!!!!!!!!!
```

The above code has 2 problems, 
Need to add file extensions in for loop at a common place, instead of running for each extension. However, this method fails, not sure this needs to be changed.

```
SFILES=./src/*.{js,css,voff}
cp: cannot stat `./src/*.{js,css,voff}': No such file or directory
```

Second, the cp cmd fails due to below reason, need some help to figure out correct syntax.

```
cp $files ${DST}"${files//.*}".js  
1.620807da7415abaeeb47.js
cp: cannot create regular file `./dst/./src/1.620807da7415abaeeb47.js.js': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple command to do it:

```
find ./src -type f \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.css -o -name \*.woff \) -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
    dest="./dst/$(echo $(basename $line) | sed -E 's/(\..{20}\.)(js|css|woff)/\.\2/g')"
    echo Copying $line to $dest 
    cp $line $dest
done
```

Comment: `find ./src -type f | egrep '.*\.(js|css|woff)' | tr '\n' '\0'` invokes three commands to get exactly the same result as `find ./src -type f \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.css -o -name \*.woff \) -print0` with a single command.

Comment: Answer fixed @Dario

Comment: Very well :) :)

Comment: echo Processing the name change for js css woff files!!!!!!!!!!!!!
SRC=./src/
DST=./dst/
mfidx=0;
find $SRC -type f \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.css -o -name \*.woff \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
        local dest="$DST/$(echo $(basename $line) | sed -E 's/(\..{20}\.)(js|css|woff)/\.\2/g')"
        echo Copying $line to $DST
        cp $line $dest
        mfidx=$((mfidx+1))
done

echo Number of js css woff files moved is $mfidx!!!!!!!!!!
echo ""

Comment: Pls note that file extension .woff and .css should be retained.
Tried the code, but got error as: 
./processwhwwebbin.sh: line 21: local: can only be used in a function
Copying ./src/2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3.js to ./dst/
cp: missing destination file operand after `./src/2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3.js'

Comment: I fixed the error in the command. I forgot that local cannot be used outside of a function.

Comment: Now it works, Thanks @AidanLovelance

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the original code and is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob       # Make globs that match nothing expand to nothing

echo 'Process web binary files!'

echo 'Processing the name change for js, css, and woff files!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
srcfiles=( src/*.{js,css,woff} )
destdir=dst

for srcpath in "${srcfiles[@]}" ; do
    filename=${srcpath##*/}
    printf '%s\n' "$filename"

    nohash_base=${filename%.*.*}    # Remove the hash and suffix from the end
    suffix=${filename##*.}          # Remove everything up to the final '.'
    newfilename=$nohash_base.$suffix

    cp -- "$srcpath" "$destdir/$newfilename"
done

echo "Number of target files detected in srcdir ${#srcfiles[*]}!!!!!!!!!"
```

The code uses an array instead of a string to hold the list of files because it is easier (and generally safer because it can handle file with names that contain spaces and other special characters).  See [Arrays [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) for information about using arrays in Bash.

See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for information about using `${var##pattern}` etc. for extracting parts of strings.

See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why it is best to avoid uppercase variable names (such as `SFILES`).

`shopt -s nullglob` prevents strange things happening if the glob pattern(s) fail to match.  See [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803/264812) for more information.

See [Bash Pitfalls #2 (cp $file $target)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target) for why it's generally better to use `cp --` instead of plain `cp` (though it's not necessary in this case (since neither argument can begin with '-')).

It's best to keep Bash code [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean.  When run on the code in the question it identifies the key problem, and recommends the use of arrays as a way to fix it.  It also identifies several other potential problems.

Comment: Pls note file extension .woff and .css should be retained.

Comment: @Murukz-userm, the code does preserve the file extensions (js, css, and woff).  I tested it on files with the same paths as the examples in the question before I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is precedence of the expansions.  Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Process web binary files!

echo Processing the name change for js files!!!!!!!!!!!!!
sfidx=0;
SFILES=$(echo ./src/*.{js,css,voff})
DST=./dst/

for file in $SFILES
do
        new=${file##*/}                  # basename
        new="${DST}${new%\.*}.js"        # escape \ the .            
        echo "copying $file to $new"     # sanity check
        cp $file "$new"
        sfidx=$((sfidx+1))
done
echo Number of target files detected in srcdir $sfidx!!!!!!!!!!
```

With three files in ./src all named "gash" I get:

```
Process web binary files!
Processing the name change for js files!!!!!!!!!!!!!
copying ./src/gash.js to ./dst/gash.js
copying ./src/gash.css to ./dst/gash.js
copying ./src/gash.voff to ./dst/gash.js
Number of target files detected in srcdir 3!!!!!!!!!!
```

(You might be able to get around using `eval`, but that can be a security issue)

`new=${file##*/}` - remove the longest string on the left ending in / (remove leading directory names, as `basename`).  If you wanted to use the external non-shell `basename` program then it would be `new=$(basename $file)`.

`${new%\.*}` - remove the shortest string on the right starting `.` (remove the old file extension)

Comment: Pls note that the file extension .css and .woff should be retained.

Comment: @Murukz-userm: that isn't what your original post said

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to have the `find` command generate a shell script, then execute it.

```
src=./src
dst=./dst
find "$src" \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.woff -o -name \*.css \) \
  -printf 'p="%p"; f="%f"; cp "$p" "'"${dst}"'/${f%%%%.*}.${f##*.}"\n'
```

This will print the shell commands you want to execute. If they are what you want,
just pipe the output to a shell:

```
find "$src" \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.woff -o -name \*.css \) \
  -printf 'p="%p"; f="%f"; cp "$p" "'"${dst}"'/${f%%%%.*}.${f##*.}"\n'|bash
```

(or `|bash -x` if you want to see what is going on.)

If you have files named, e.g., `./src/dir1/a.xyz.js` and `./src/dir2/a.uvw.js` they will both end up as `./dst/a.js`, the second overwriting the first. To avoid this, you might want to use `cp -i` instead of `cp`.

If you are absolutely sure that there will never be spaces or other strange characters in your pathnames, you can use less quotes (to the horror of some shell purists)

```
find $src \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.woff -o -name \*.css \) \
  -printf "p=%p; f=%f; cp \$p ${dst}/\${f%%%%.*}.\${f##*.}\\n"|bash
```

Some final remarks:

- `%p` and `%f` are expanded by `-printf` as the full pathname and the basename of the processed file. they enable us to avoid the `basename` command. Unfortunately, the is no such directive for the file extension, so we must use brace expansion in the shell to compose the final name.
- In the `-printf` argument, we must use `%%` to write a single percent character. Since we need two of them, there have to be four...
- `${f%%.*}` expands in the shell as the value of `$f` with everything removed from the first dot onwards
- `${f##*.}` expands in the shell as the value of `$f` with everything removed up to the last dot (i.e., it expands to the file extension)

Comment: Pls note file extension .woff and .css should be retained

Comment: `${##*.}` is the file extension (read my last remark) and it is retained.

Comment: Noting not copied
p="./src/2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3.js"; f="2.93e8bd3b179a0199a6a3.js"; cp "$p" "./dst//${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"

Comment: Please read _all_ my answer. You ran the code which does nothing but print the commands to be given to the shell. The code to actually execute them is on the next paragraph, together with a remark on how to get a verbose output (option `-x` to the subshell)